# Comparing elements in 2 arrays to a percentage tolerence

Tags: matlab

I am trying to compare a four element array containing some results with 5 other four element array to see if they are equal. For this I can use isequal. The problem I am having is that I would like to allow a small bit of error (~2%) and still get the a logical yes output for each matching element.

I could run through loads of IF loops bur I feel like there should be a simple way to implement this but I can't figure it out.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated as I am stumped on this seemingly simple problem.

Thanks.

An example is below. y is within 1% of x1 but still I get not a match. The reason I want to see if it matches all 4 elements, or just one or whatever, is that I can use this information later on.

```
x1= [0.012 1.323 0.1423 3.458];
x2= [0.341 2.973 0.234 1.234];
x3= [3.093 2.324 4.321 3.234];
x4= [0.987 2.345 2.543 3.243];

y= [0.0121    1.3362    0.1437    3.4926];

y1 =(x1==y)
y2 =(x2==y)
y3 =(x3==y)
y4 =(x4==y)

if sum (y1) == 4
    display ('y equals x1')
elseif sum(y2) == 4
    display ('y equals x2')
elseif sum(y3) == 4
    display ('y equals x3')
elseif sum(y4)== 4
display ('y equals x4')
else 
    display ('Unknown')
end
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: What is your criteria for a logical one? How do you compare them? Does all values in all arrays have to be equal?

Comment: Thanks to user over at reddit: If I use `norm(y-x1)/norm(x1) < 0.02` I can get and answer of 1 if is it is a match to within 2% which is very useful. However I was hoping to get answer in form ans=[1 0 1 1] if, say, element 1,3,4 were within 2% but 3 wasn't. Apologies if I am being vague I'm just having a hard time explaining what's in my head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one suggestion. Create an error matrix such as

```
err1=abs((x1-y)./y);
```

This will give you the percentage error in x. Remember to use ./ for element-wise division. For some situations you might want to divide by x or not take the absolute value.

Then you can compare your error to your tolerance.

```
y1=(err1<0.02);
```

This should give you a binary array as you desire.